# How to calculate the timestamp for the end of a call when given the timestamp for the start of the call and the duration of the call in hh:mi:ss?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a field labeled Call_Timestamp which is the date/time at which a call begins.  I then have a field labeled Call_Time which is the duration of the call in hh:mi:ss.  How would I add the Call_Time to the Call_Timestamp to get a timestamp for the end of the call?  Thank you!

Comment: If you're storing the duration of the call in a string, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Not an Oracle expert, but `Call_Time` should be of type [`INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Interval#INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND).  If it's a VARCHAR2, then use [TO_DSINTERVAL(`'0'||Call_Time`)](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/TO_DSINTERVAL) to convert it to an interval, which can then be added to an existing timestamp (`Call_Timestamp`) to get a new timestamp of when the call ends.  I believe you should be able to add an interval to a timestamp with the `+` operator.

Comment: @BaconBits has the correct answer. Though I believe a space is needed between the hour and day. Try adding a space behind the zero if you run into issues.

Comment: What is the data type of `call_timestamp` and `call_time`? (Note: although the first one is called "timestamp" it may in fact be `varchar2`, not timestamp.) The answer to your question depends heavily on this crucial detail which is missing from your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT call_timestamp + ( TO_TIMESTAMP( call_time, 'HH24:MI:SS' )
                        - TO_TIMESTAMP( '00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS' ) )
         AS call_end_timestamp
FROM   your_table
```

or:

```
SELECT call_timestamp + TO_DSINTERVAL( '0 ' || call_time )
         AS call_end_timestamp
FROM   your_table;
```

Even better would be to store the `CALL_TIME` field as an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` type then you can just add the two:

```
SELECT call_timestamp + call_time AS call_end_timestamp
FROM   your_table
```